# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of null in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to validate email in a form input by a button click.
Here is the code:

```
function ValidateEmail(inputText) {
  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  if (inputText.value.match(mailformat)) {
    document.form1.coemail.focus();
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('You have entered an invalid email address!Enter again');
    document.getElementById('form1').reset();
    return false;
  }
}

<button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button"onClick="ValidateEmail(document.form1.coemail)">Next</button>
```

On clicking the Next button I get an alert message correctly but after that it redirects to next page instead of resetting the current one.
On inspecting element in chrome's console,I found this error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of null**

Where am I wrong here ?

Comment: Apparently the html element with id "form1" couldn't be found in the document.

Comment: Post your form code. form has id `form1`?

Comment: @A.J Yes . <form role="form" name="form1" action="reg_employer.php" method="post">

Comment: @shri_wahal: try the way i answered, or add id t form as `<form id="form1" role="form" name="form1" action="reg_employer.php" method="post"> `

Comment: @m69 Thank you so much for pointing out the error :) It now works perfectly !! Cheers . Apparently I didnt have a form id .

Comment: @A.J Yes I figured that out .thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `id` to your form:

`<form id="form1" role="form" name="form1" action="reg_employer.php" method="post">`

**or**

Try:

```
function ValidateEmail(inputText)
{
  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  if(inputText.value.match(mailformat))
{
  document.form1.coemail.focus();
  return true;

}
else
{
  alert("You have entered an invalid email address!Enter again");
  document.form1.reset();   //<== change this line, use form name
  return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I didn't have a form id in

```
<form id="form1" role="form" name="form1" action="reg_employer.php" method="post">
```

Addition of a form id resolved the issue.